# Remove duplicate columns from Query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me!! Newby with Sql queries

```
Select * 
from(
    select  EmpID,  
            sum(IncomeTax) as TaxAmount,
            sum(bsalary) as SalaryAmount 
    from PayrollHistory   Pay 
    group by EmpID
) cumSalary
Right JOIN (
    Select  PayrollHistory.EmpID,
            (select firstName +'  '+coalesce(middleInitial,' ')+' '+ lastName  
            from Employee 
            where Employee.EmpID=PayrollHistory.EmpID)as   name,
            PayrollHistory.IncomeTax,
            (PayrollHistory.bsalary+sum(ISNULL(Allw.amount,0)))totalTaxableSUM
    from PayrollHistory  
    left join (
            select * 
            from AllowanceHistory 
            where AllowanceHistory.taxStatus=1  
            ) as Allw 
        on Allw.EmpID=PayrollHistory.EmpID and Allw.payMonth=PayrollHistory.payMonth  
    where PayrollHistory.payMonth=3
    group by  PayrollHistory.EmpID, PayrollHistory.IncomeTax, PayrollHistory.bsalary
) as tbl 
    on tbl.EmpID =cumSalary.EmpID
```

The above query result gives 2 EmpID rows that are the same. How can remove one of them and still get the same result

Comment: This code is very hard to read. Can you maybe apply some formatting?

Comment: Please specify your problem. Do you get duplicate rows or duplicate columns?

Comment: Show us an output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use column name selection instead of using * , refer as below

```
Select cumSalary.*,PayrollHistory.name , **....etc** from(
select EmpID,  sum(IncomeTax) as TaxAmount,sum(bsalary) as SalaryAmount from     
PayrollHistory   Pay group by EmpID
) cumSalary
Right JOIN (
Select PayrollHistory.EmpID,(select firstName +'  '+coalesce(middleInitial,'   
')+' '+ lastName from Employee where   
 Employee.EmpID=PayrollHistory.EmpID)as   name,
  PayrollHistory.IncomeTax,(         PayrollHistory.bsalary+sum(ISNULL(Allw.amount,0)  
))totalTaxableSUM
from PayrollHistory  
left join (select * from AllowanceHistory where AllowanceHistory.taxStatus=1  
) as Allw on 
Allw.EmpID=PayrollHistory.EmpID and Allw.payMonth=PayrollHistory.payMonth  
where PayrollHistory.payMonth=3
group by   
PayrollHistory.EmpID,PayrollHistory.IncomeTax,PayrollHistory.bsalary
) as tbl on tbl.EmpID =cumSalary.EmpID
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of first `Select *` specify all rows that you need like:

```
select  cumSalary.EmpID,  
        cumSalary.TaxAmount,
        cumSalary.SalaryAmount,
        tbl.name,
        tbl.IncomeTax,
        tbl.totalTaxableSUM
```

etc.